# solution to index.php in my cakephp application

Tags: cakephp

If i ignore index.php from my url the control not passing to the controller correctly. How to avoid the index.php from the url's.

ex:http://localhost/index.php/home/display

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up mod_rewrite in your apache (via config or .htaccess). Then all request will be redirected to correct controllers/actions without having to add index.php in the URL. [This](http://book.cakephp.org/view/37/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess) should help you set your server correctly.